# Problem in code while interfacing PIC24 with 25AA256 EEPROM

Tags: microcontroller, pic, spi, c, eeprom

I have been trying to interface a PIC24FJ128GA010 with a 25AA256 EEPROM using Proteus and Serial Peripheral Interface (SPI).
I wrote a C code and configured everything and all pins but since I self learned this software, I am having an issue while simulating the project.
I will attach below a picture of the circuit and will put my code and explain about them.

[image]

As you can see, on the left is the PIC24 microcontroller, the component named U2 is a ZIGBEE coordinator which is excluded for now from my experiment, and the component U3 which is the EEPROM.
**Note that no other circuitry is made in this circuit.**

The pins are configured as follows:

- Pin 12 on the microcontroller, which is SDO2 is an output pin connected to pin 5 on the EEPROM (SI)
- All the other pins that are connected to the EEPROM are considered input pins to the microcontroller.

Below you will see the code with comments.

```
/*
...
 */

#include <p24FJ128GA010.h>
#include <xc.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define FCY 8000000
#include <libpic30.h>  // Include for delay functions

// CONFIG2
#pragma config POSCMOD = NONE           // Primary Oscillator Select (Primary oscillator disabled)
#pragma config OSCIOFNC = OFF           // Primary Oscillator Output Function (OSC2/CLKO/RC15 functions as CLKO (FOSC/2))
#pragma config FCKSM = CSDCMD           // Clock Switching and Monitor (Clock switching and Fail-Safe Clock Monitor are disabled)
//#pragma config FNOSC = FRCDIV           // Oscillator Select (Fast RC Oscillator with Postscaler (FRCDIV))
#pragma config IESO = ON                // Internal External Switch Over Mode (IESO mode (Two-Speed Start-up) enabled)

// CONFIG1
#pragma config WDTPS = PS32768          // Watchdog Timer Postscaler (1:32,768)
#pragma config FWPSA = PR128            // WDT Prescaler (Prescaler ratio of 1:128)
#pragma config WINDIS = ON              // Watchdog Timer Window (Standard Watchdog Timer enabled,(Windowed-mode is disabled))
#pragma config FWDTEN = ON              // Watchdog Timer Enable (Watchdog Timer is enabled)
#pragma config ICS = PGx2               // Comm Channel Select (Emulator/debugger uses EMUC2/EMUD2)
#pragma config GWRP = OFF               // General Code Segment Write Protect (Writes to program memory are allowed)
#pragma config GCP = OFF                // General Code Segment Code Protect (Code protection is disabled)
#pragma config JTAGEN = ON              // JTAG Port Enable (JTAG port is enabled)

//THIS IS PIN CONFIGURATION FOR THE ZIGBEE COORDINATOR
#define CS_ LATFbits.LATF0
#define WAKE    LATFbits.LATF1
#define RESET_  LATFbits.LATF2
#define SCK     LATFbits.LATF6
#define MOSI    LATFbits.LATF8
#define MISO    PORTFbits.RF7   
#define INT PORTEbits.RE8

//THIS IS PIN CONFIGURATION FOR THE EEPROM
#define SCK_EE  LATGbits.LATG6
#define CS_EE   LATGbits.LATG0
#define WP_EE   LATGbits.LATG1
#define HOLD_EE LATGbits.LATG2
#define MOSI_EE LATGbits.LATG8
#define MISO_EE PORTGbits.RG7


unsigned char writeSPIByte(unsigned char transmit) { //function to write a byte
    unsigned char received = 0;
    unsigned char bits = 8;
    unsigned char tmpbit = 0;

    SCK = 0;

    //make the transmission
    unsigned char mask = 0x80; //Initialize to write and read bit 7
    unsigned char ret = 0; //Initialize read byte with 0

    do {
        //Clock out current bit onto SPI Out line
        if (transmit & mask)
            MOSI = 1;
        else
            MOSI = 0;
        SCK = 1; //Set SPI Clock line
        if (MISO)
            ret |= mask; //Read current bit fromSPI In line
        __delay_us(1); //Ensure minimum delay of 500nS between SPI Clock high and SPI Clock Low
        SCK = 0; //Set SPI Clock line
        mask = mask >> 1; //Shift mask so that next bit is written and read from SPI lines
        __delay_us(1); //Ensure minimum delay of 1000ns between bits
    } while (mask != 0);

    return ret;
}

unsigned char readSPIByte() { //function to read a byte
    unsigned char data;
    data = writeSPIByte(0x00);
    return data;
}

unsigned char writeEEPROMByte(unsigned int address, unsigned char data) {
    // Select EEPROM chip
    CS_EE = 0;

    // Send Write Enable command to EEPROM (if needed)
    writeSPIByte(0x06); // Write Enable command

    // Send Write command and address to EEPROM
    writeSPIByte(0x02); // Write command
    writeSPIByte((address >> 8) & 0xFF); // High byte of address
    writeSPIByte(address & 0xFF); // Low byte of address

    // Send data byte to write
    writeSPIByte(data);

    // Deselect EEPROM chip
    CS_EE = 1;

    // Wait for EEPROM write to complete (may vary depending on EEPROM)
    __delay_us(2);

    return data;
}

unsigned char readEEPROMByte(unsigned int address) {
    // Select EEPROM chip
    CS_EE = 0;

    // Send Read command and address to EEPROM
    writeSPIByte(0x03); // Read command
    writeSPIByte((address >> 8) & 0xFF); // High byte of address
    writeSPIByte(address & 0xFF); // Low byte of address

    // Read data byte from EEPROM
    unsigned char data = readSPIByte();

    // Deselect EEPROM chip
    CS_EE = 1;

    return data;
}

int main() {
    // Initialize your microcontroller and SPI settings
    IFS0bits.SPI1IF = 0; //Clear the Interrupt Flag
    IEC0bits.SPI1IE = 0; //Disable the Interrupt  

    // SPI1CON1 Register Settings
    SPI1CON1bits.DISSCK = 1; //Internal Serial Clock is Enabled
    SPI1CON1bits.DISSDO = 0; //SDOx pin is controlled by the module
    SPI1CON1bits.MODE16 = 0; //Communication is word-wide (16 bits)
    SPI1CON1bits.SMP = 0; //Input Data is sampled at the middle of data output time
    SPI1CON1bits.CKE = 0; //Serial output data changes on transition from
    //Idle clock state to active clock state
    SPI1CON1bits.CKP = 0; //Idle state for clock is a low level;
    //active state is a high level
    SPI1CON1bits.MSTEN = 1; //Master Mode Enabled
    SPI1CON2bits.SPIBEN = 1;
    SPI1STATbits.SPIROV = 0;
    SPI1STATbits.SPIEN = 1; //Enable SPI Module
    SPI1BUF = 0x0000; //Write data to be transmitted  

    //Interrupt Controller Settings
    IFS0bits.SPI1IF = 0; //Clear the Interrupt Flag
    IEC0bits.SPI1IE = 1; //Enable the Interrupt

    // Example usage: Write data to EEPROM at address 0x1234
    unsigned char dataToWrite = 0xAA;
    unsigned int addressToWrite = 0x1234;
    writeEEPROMByte(addressToWrite, dataToWrite);

    // Example usage: Read data from EEPROM at address 0x1234
    unsigned int addressToRead = 0x1234;
    unsigned char readData = readEEPROMByte(addressToRead);

    printf("Read data from EEPROM: 0x%02X\n", readData);

    return 0;
}
```

First of all, I want to ask you if you think that my code will work. I already built it and compiled successfully. But is the logic correct? Because it won't simulate.

Below are the errors that are shown:

[image]

Any hep would be appreciated.

Comment: It's rather safe to say it won't work for multiple reasons. Try to fix the simulation to work so you can test your code.

Comment: I'm not understanding what the problem is, I checked that path and seems that everything is okay. When I was trying to run the code, it used to tell me to change the file format from coff to elf, so i changed everything from coff to elf.  Could it be that i should select the hierarchy model?

Comment: I don't have a clue but regardless of what you changed from COFF to ELF, the simulator still tries to load the COFF file.

Comment: The error has apparently nothing to do with SPI and your specific application. The executable has an unsupported format, and you need to fix the build of it. BTW, do not post screenshots of text, in this case please copy the content of the Simulation Errors view _as text_ into your question.